# Get controller name in Bootstrap

Tags: zend-framework, model-view-controller, controller, bootstrapping

I want to load an extra config file based on the controller's name in my bootstrap file, so I have to get the name of the controller in bootstrap (in Zend Framework 1.1). Is this possible?

I've tried:

```
$front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
$controller = $front->getRequest()->getControllerName();
```

But this doesn't work:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getControllerName() on a non-object in [path]\application\Bootstrap.php on line 10
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must bootstrap the front controller first to be able to use it.

```
$bootstrap->bootstrap('frontController');
$front = $bootstrap->frontController;
$controller = $front->getRequest()->getControllerName();
```

Answer (score 6):

You can do it like this also:

```
        $router = new Zend_Controller_Router_Rewrite();
        $request = new Zend_Controller_Request_Http();
        $router->route($request);
        $request->getActionName();
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to initialize the request object first by bootstrapping the front controller

Example for usage in Bootstrap class:

```
$this->bootstrap('frontController');
$request = $this->getResource('frontController')->getRequest();
$controller = $request->getControllerName();
```

You should not use the request object in your bootstrap file through.

The better solution would be to use a front controller plugin and its `pre-/postDispatch()` methods to achieve this.

If you have more complex logic behind it or you need further convinience methods for each controller you may extend the Zend_Controller_Action class.

Comment: I added Songos solution and wrote it a bit more understandable.

Comment: Sorry, but the original answer was to parse the URL myself, so I can't upvote that, especially when completely changing the whole answer. Can't believe people upvoted this more than the accepted answer.